# Speak only required webpage elements using TalkBack in Android

Tags: android, android-webview, accessibility

I develop an application to access a particular website for visually impaired people. I used the WebView to load the URL which I wanted. When I enable the TalkBack feature, it provides spoken feedback for everything the user touch.
But I want to make speak only few elements of the website. Is it possible to implement?

Comment: "But I want to make speak only few elements of the website" -- what do you propose to do for the rest? After all, people are usually visually impaired for all elements of a Web page, not just some.

Comment: Can you provide current code example?

Comment: @CommonsWare for an example login form of the website. When the user want to login he only needs to access textfileds for username, password etc. The purpose of my idea is to reduce the complexity by speaking everyting, everytime touch.

Comment: @Nishu    webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    WebView.HitTestResult hr = ((WebView) v).getHitTestResult();
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
     switch (hr.getType()) {
     case 9:
      tts.speak("Enter <element name>", 2, null);
      break;
     }
    }
    return false;
   }
  });